# Analyze if this series converges: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}+1}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, ratio

Analyze if this series converges: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}+1}{n!}$

I have used ratio test: $\lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\left |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}  \right |< 1$

$\Rightarrow$

$\lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\left | \frac{(n+1)^{2}+1}{(n+1)!}:\frac{n^{2}+1}{n!} \right | = \lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\frac{((n+1)^{2}+1)n!}{(n+1)!*(n^{2}+1)}$

$= \lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\frac{(n+1)^{2}+1}{(n+1)*(n^{2}+1)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\frac{n^{2}+2n+2}{n^{3}+n^{2}+n+1}$

The denominator is bigger than the enumerator, so we got $\infty > 1$ and thus the sequence will diverge. (Can I just say that or this requires an additional proof? We got a $n^{2}$ in the enumerator and a $n^{3}$ in the denominator...?)

Did I do it correctly?

**Edit: Converges absolutely to $0$ and NOT $\infty$**

Comment: That limit tends to $0$, not $\infty$, so the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: I think you want to flip your conclusion. Since the denominator grows faster than the numerator, the limit of that final quotient will go to zero and the series will converge.

Comment: The denominator has more terms when you expand it. Why should it imply the limit is $\infty$?

Comment: Thank you, you are totally right I have confused that badly!
Everything else is fine?

Comment: All terms are positive and it has more than one term so it can not converge to 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to provide a concrete underpinning to this general reasoning: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}x^n=e^x$$
Differentiate and then multiply by $x$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}x^n=xe^x$$
Differentiate and then multiply by $x$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}x^n=x(x+1)e^x$$
Adding the first and last equations:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n!}x^n=(x^2+x+1)e^x$$
So the value of your sum is $3e$.

Comment: Also note that by the same procedure you can easily expand to find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{P(n)}{n!}$ for any polynomial $P(n)$.

Answer (score 3):

The main term goes to zero so fast that any crude comparison gives absolute convergence.
Moreover, the value of the series is simple to compute:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n^2+1}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n(n-1)+n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{(n-2)!} = \color{red}{3e}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake at the final step to make a conclusion. :)

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\left |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}  \right |=0$ then the series converges absolutely.

Also, we don't know the value of the sum so it is still wrong to say **it converges absolutely to $0$**! The ratio test just tells us that the limit

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{n^{2}+1}{n!}$$

exists but it says nothing about the value of the limit! :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Observe that 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2}+2n+2}{n^{3}+n^{2}+n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^3} }{ 1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}}=\frac{0}{1}=0 $$

Answer (score 1):

The limit of a rational function (quotient of two polynomials) at $\infty$ is the limit of the ratio  of the *highest degree terms*, namely
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2}+2n+2}{n^{3}+n^{2}+n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{n^{3}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0.$$